# html/css for brackets around mathematical matrix -- prefer lightweight

Tags: html, math, matrix

I'm writing up some math in html.  I want to do it in a small and lightweight fashion.  This is what I have so far.  It makes the matrices just fine, but is there a way I can do the brackets one typically sees around matrices?

```
For example, if <b>A</b> is the matrix
<br>
<br>
<div align=center>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1+3i</td>
            <td>2+i</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4-3i</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>-2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NQ6ww/38/

Done via CSS using `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to simulate the square brackets.

```css
    .matrix {
        position: relative;
    }
    .matrix:before, .matrix:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 6px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .matrix:before {
        left: -6px;
        border-right: 0;
    }
    .matrix:after {
        right: -6px;
        border-left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div align=center>
    <table class="matrix">
        <tr>
            <td>1+3i</td>
            <td>2+i</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4-3i</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>-2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A MathJax-based solution (with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wFZg/)):

```
<script src=
"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">
</script>
\[\begin{bmatrix}
1+3\mathrm{i}  & 2+\mathrm{i} & 10\\
4-3\mathrm{i} & 5 & -2
\end{bmatrix}\]
```

It seems to be increasingly common to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) for displaying math formulas on web pages. The example above used the LaTeX version of the approach. MathJax is based on client-side JavaScript, but this downside is probably outweighed by the benefits.

The use of `\bmatrix` generates a matrix with brackets. The primary notation for matrices, according to ISO 80000-2, uses parentheses; for this, use `\pmatrix` instead.

I have used `\mathrm{i}` to produce non-italicized “i” as per the standard. Many mathematicians still favor italics here, achievable by using just `i` instead, since LaTeX italicizes identifiers by default. Note that LaTeX automatically applies proper spacing around operators and turns the hyphen “-” to a minus sign.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).